# Flask, Marshmallow and Sqlalchemy factory problems

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, factory, marshmallow

I am building a Flask RESTful application and I'm trying to build it with a factory design pattern but I think I'm missing something. Here are my set up files

app.py: `

```
from src import create_app, ext_celery

app = create_app("development")
celery = ext_celery.celery
```

src/**init**.py:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
ext_celery = FlaskCeleryExt(create_celery_app=make_celery)

def create_app(config_name=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    db.init_app(app)
    ext_celery.init_app(app)

    api = Api(app, errors=errors)
    initialize_routes(api)

    return app
```

My problem is in the user/view.py file. If I try put the db import statement at the top of the file I get a circular reference error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'src' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/src/__init__.py)`

so I have to move it inside of the method in order for it to work. My user/view.py put function looks like this:

```
    @token_required
    def put(self, user):
        data = request.json
        from .schema import user_get_schema
        from src import db
        updated_user = user_get_schema.load(data, session=db.session)
        from models import Users
        ...
```

I get the same issue if I try to import the schema or the models above the method call. Is this how it's supposed to work? I have to import these items for EVERY view? That doesn't seem right to me but I can't figure out how else to do it. I'm still trying to learn Python.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using a circular import. You should move all connection 3rd app to another file like src/extension.py

**src/extension.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_celeryext import FlaskCeleryExt


db = SQLAlchemy()
ext_celery = FlaskCeleryExt(create_celery_app=make_celery)
```

**src/init.py:**

```
from src.extension import db, ext_celery

def create_app(config_name=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    db.init_app(app)
    ext_celery.init_app(app)

    api = Api(app, errors=errors)
    initialize_routes(api)

    return app
```

In all file models or view you will use `from src.extension import db`. Now all file will import from one connection from one file to avoid circular import

Answer (score 0):

That gets me one step closer but I have a context problem in my models class now:

```
class Models:
    Base = automap_base()
    from app import app
    with app.app_context():
        Base.prepare(autoload_with=db.engine)
    Users = Base.classes.users
```

how do I get access to the app_context() without the circular import?

**update**

I hate hacks like this but I also hate spending the several days turning in circles trying to figure out something that I don't understand. So I'm creating an entirely new Flask app in models in order to gain access to context...ugh

```
config_name = os.environ.get("FLASK_CONFIG", "development")
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
Base = automap_base()
with app.app_context():
    Base.prepare(autoload_with=db.engine)
```

Comment: Why you use app_context in model. See this post, hope this help you https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-context

Comment: I am - but I can't get access to the original app in order to call it without a circular reference